# Test for table/view existence with Scalaquery & create if not present

Tags: sql, scala, scalaquery

I am writing some tests to automate checking if a database (a MS SQL 
Server instance) has certain views, and if it does not, creating those 
views using the `BasicTable` object. 
Something like:

```
  @Test def CheckAndBuildViewsOnDB() = { 
    VerifyViewExists(FooTable, BarTable) //FooTable et al defined as: 
FooTable extends BasicTable[Foo], where Foo is a case class & FooTable 
has a DDL create defined. 
  }
```

Based on this and cribbing from [Stefan Zeiger's `assertTablesExist` example](https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/scalaquery/test/util/TestDB.scala), I made a little method to check the db for a view, and if the 
check throws an exception call that view's `BasicTable ddl.create`:

```
  def VerifyViewExists(views:BasicTable*) = { 
    DatabaseSession.session() withSession { //helper class which 
initiates a db connection & session 
      views map { 
        v => (try queryNA[Int]("select 1 from '"+ v.tableName +"' 
where 1<0").list 
            catch {case _: Exception => v.ddl.create; 
println("Couldn't find view "+v.tableName+", creating it 
now...");}) 
      } } }
```

Which seems reasonable to me, but has two problems:

1. this isn't the right way to type the views parameter as `BasicTable`, 
   resulting in `"error: class BasicTable takes type parameters"`
2. something funky is happening with the map argument v's scope, 
   resulting in `"error: value tableName is not a member of type parameter 
   T0"`.

Pardon my ignorance with this question, as I suspect that the root of 
my issue lies with not understanding Scala's type system. 
Along with those two problems is the nagging feeling that I haven't 
really done `VerifyViewExists` in the most succinct or readable style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care what the type parameter is, you should be able to solve #1 by adding [_]:

```
def VerifyViewExists(views:BasicTable[_]*) = {
```

My guess is that fixing #1 will cause #2 to disappear.

By the way it may be better to write foreach rather than map, since the latter will collect the results into a new collection, which I don't think you want.

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax bit I was missing. Thanks!